# spring-integration-kafka annotation support & example

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

Although new to spring, I'm usually able to get started with a spring projects fairly well with annotations only. The official examples uses xml without mentioning where they will be placed etc.

Is there any sample project on reading from a kafka topic? Preferably by using annotation to set the zk & kafka configuration properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, take a look to the [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference) project and here is a [`KafkaTests`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/kafka/KafkaTests.java) to demonstrate how to be for your case.

Plus here you are Josh Long's article: https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/15/using-apache-kafka-for-integration-and-data-processing-pipelines-with-spring